# The value from a prompt box when ESC is pressed

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have this simple function

```
function Login()
{
var x=prompt("Please enter your name","");
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// Използваните браузъри
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// Кой ли ползва тези версии..
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","login.php?u="+x,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

The problem is when the user decide to exit the prompt box by clicking ESC.Can someone explain to me what exactly happen with the variable x in this case.I get to the conclusion that it get assignied with the value 'null' and by null I mean a string, because when I check with

```
If(!is_null($u))
```

my script doesn't work, but if I replace this with

```
If($u!='null')
```

then everything works just fine, so could someone explain me what in fact is happening with the prompt box value when you exit it with pressin ESC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns as if you had clicked cancel.

It is `null` not as a string ..

```
alert( prompt('') === null );
```

will alert `true` if you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or cancel button

Comment: Then why when I get the value of x in the PHP file and do the check

Comment: @Leron, the value is actual `null`. but you implicitly convert it to a string since you add it to one, when you do the `"login.php?u="+x`. In javascript try `alert(typeof null)` and `alert(typeof (''+null) )`. So yes in the PHP side you will receive `"null"` as a string.

Answer (score 1):

`x` will receive the `null` value when the user cancels the prompt, so:

```
var x=prompt("Please enter your name","");
if (x === null) {
    // User canceled
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/oxebi5/3)